# Change jquery code for mobile users

Tags: jquery, mobile

I just launched my new website - mollycampbelldesign.com

While it doesn't adapt to mobile users yet, I decided to just get the site up and continue forward as I go. The only problem so far, is the phone icon in the top left - right now you can only toggle the phone number by clicking on the phone icon. I did that so mobile users can click on the phone # without making the box slide out. But when you're viewing on a desktop, it would be nice to be able to click the entire number box to make it disappear. Is there a way to make mobile users get one set of code, and desktop users get another?

HTML code:

```
<div class="call-button"><p>Call Now: <a href="tel:8013827471">801-382-7471</a></p> <img src="/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/phone.gif" alt="Call Now"/></div>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".call-button img").toggle(
   function() {
     $(".call-button").animate({ left: "0" }, 1000 );}, 
   function() { 
    $(".call-button").animate({ left: "-225px" }, 1000 );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty way:

```
var isTouchDevice = "ontouchstart" in window;
if(isTouchDevice){
   //do mobile stuff
}
```